# SPARQL: How to get an insance of an ontology, if depth of the class hierarchy is unknown?

Tags: semantics, sparql, jena, ontology

I have a question about SPARQL.  I have an ontology of animals:

```
Animals  (is a superclass with object property <hasColor>)
------ Mammals (subclass of Animals)
------------- Dog (subclass of Mammals)
---------------- dog1 (a instance with property <hasColor>="white")
---------------- dog2 (a instance with property <hasColor>="red"   )
------ Bird (subclass of Animals)
```

**Is it possible to find with SPARQL  "all Animals, that are 'white' "  or  "all instances of Animals"? And backwards: How can I know,  if a instance (dog1) belongs to Animals?**

**NOTE**: The depth and breadth of the class hierarchy is unknown in advance.

Also the query below will not work

```
SELECT ?x WHERE  {?x rdfs:subClassOf  :Animals .  ?x :hasСolor "white"}
```

And the next query (find all Animals, that are 'white')  works only if the depth of class hierarchy is known.
(So if the hierarchy is known, can I make the specified steps (from top of hierarchy to bottom) to reach the goal: in this case 2 steps.

```
SELECT ?z WHERE  {
?x  rdfs:subClassOf :Animals .
?y  rdfs:subClassOf ?x .
?z  rdf:type ?y .
?z :hasColor "white"
}
```

The same is true for the next example - "find all instances  of Animals"

```
SELECT ?z WHERE  {
?x  rdfs:subClassOf :Animals .
?y  rdfs:subClassOf ?x .
?z  rdf:type ?y .
}
```

What to do, if the hierarchie is unknown?

The query will be processed with **SDB** (is a component of **Jena**).

I want something like : 
`select ?x where {?x rdfs:subClassOf  :Animals .  ?x :hasСolor "white"})`

**UPD.** Solution for "find all Animals (instances), that are 'white'" might look like this:

> SELECT ?y WHERE { ?x rdfs:subClassOf* :Animals . ?y rdf:type ?x .  ?y
>   :hasColor "white"}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use transitivity in your SPARQL query (using *) :

```
SELECT ?y WHERE { ?x rdfs:subClassOf* :Animals . 
                  ?y rdf:type ?x . 
                  ?y :hasColor "white" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested the query with Protege.
SELECT ?x WHERE  {?x rdfs:subClassOf*  :Animals } works fine.
But SELECT ?x WHERE  {?x rdfs:subClassOf*  :Animals .  ?x :hasСolor "white"} find no matches

Comment: its strange the query SELECT ?x ?y WHERE {?x rdfs:subClassOf* :Animals . ?y  rdf:type ?x ."} works fine too and returns all instances, but if adding (?x :hasСolor "white") finds it no matches

Comment: @ERG : and what about `SELECT ?x WHERE  {?x rdfs:subClassOf*  :Animals .  ?y rdf:type ?x . ?y :hasColor "white"}` ?

Comment: That query will return all classes that is a descendant of Animals and have a colour "white".  What you want is to find all instances of such classes, where the instance has a the colour "white".  Something like this "SELECT ?x WHERE  {?t rdfs:subClassOf*  :Animals . ?x a t . ?x :hasСolor "white"}